# Split address based on line feeds chr(13) on Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

So if we have the following data:

```
"3 Webster Close
Sible Hedingham",
"2 School Road ",
"51 Belfield Avenue
East Calder",
"Clearvu

Manns Hill

",
"179 Delffordd
Rhos
Pontardawe

"
```

I can get the first line from the data no problem and know that each new line starts with a line feed(chr13), but I want it to stop at the NEXT line feed so that the last one on the list, would be as follows:

- Line 1 is :- 179 delffordd
- Line 2 is :- Rhose
- Line 3 is :- Pontardawe

I primarily am concerned with only line 1 & 2(forgetting line 3 from the above example) to split but not sure how it would be possible?

The following works but put `Rhose` and `Pontardawe` are shown within line 2. I am not sure if I can apply the same logic as I did with the REGEXP to perhaps use (.*) x 2?

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR (trim(street), '(.*)$',1,1,'m') as addresslineone,
case 
when instr(street,chr(10)) > 0
then replace(substr(replace(trim(street),chr(13),''), instr(replace(trim(street),chr(13),''),chr(10))+1,  length(replace(trim(street),chr(13),''))-instr(replace(trim(street),chr(13),''),chr(10))+1),chr(10),'')
end as addresslinetwo
```

Produces:
Addresslineone          Addresslinetwo

179 Delfford            Rhose Pontardawe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` with `regexp_substr` like this:

```
    select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR (regexp_replace(trim(street),'"',''),'(.*)'||chr(10)||'*',1,1,'i',1) first,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (regexp_replace(trim(street),'"',''),'(.*)'||chr(10)||'*',1,2,'i',1) second,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (regexp_replace(trim(street),'"',''),'(.*)'||chr(10)||'*',1,3,'i',1) third
from (select
'"179 Delffordd
Rhos
Pontardawe

"' street from dual union all select '"3 Webster Close Sible Hedingha"' from dual)
```

First remove `""` characters with `regexp_replace`, and then get first,second and third values using `regexp_substr`.
This returns:

```
FIRST                            SECOND   THIRD                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
179 Delffordd                    Rhos     Pontardawe                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 Webster Close Sible Hedingha                                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That does not work, or I may have misrepresented the question. It should be setting the "Rhos" part of the string as the second column. What your SQL did is just bring back what it had in the first place.

Comment: Perfect, I believe it was my lack of understanding of occurrences which threw me off. Thank you for that.